# How to execute a linux process in a node app deployed in Bluemix?

Tags: node.js, linux, ibm-cloud

I have a basic node app deployed in bluemix. I want to run ffmpeg to perform video conversions, and I uploaded it to the repository. However, it is never executed. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide the code that you are using so that the community can help you with your issue. If you are seeing error messages, please include that information as well. What services are you using on Bluemix? There is not enough information here to help.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code examples I can try and take a shot at helping- you can run commands through your node.js app using child process. Here's an example for you:

Make sure to add the `child_process` dependency in your package.json

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var child1 = cp.exec("ls", function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  if(err){
    console.log("Error listing: " + err + "STDOUT: " + stdout + " STDERR: " + stderr);
    child1.kill();
  }
  else{
    console.log("The output of 'ls' is: " + stdout);
    child1.kill();
  }
});
```

After your push to Bluemix, view your logs `cf logs <app_name> --recent` and you will see the output

```
2016-09-01T16:50:51.99-0400 [App/0]      OUT The output of 'ls' is: bin
2016-09-01T16:50:51.99-0400 [App/0]      OUT index.js
2016-09-01T16:50:51.99-0400 [App/0]      OUT node_modules
2016-09-01T16:50:51.99-0400 [App/0]      OUT package.json
2016-09-01T16:50:51.99-0400 [App/0]      OUT Procfile
2016-09-01T16:50:51.99-0400 [App/0]      OUT runtime.pid
2016-09-01T16:50:51.99-0400 [App/0]      OUT vendor
```